# Regression testing in rails using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, rspec-rails, regression-testing

I know that Rspec is a tool for testing, it covers BDD and TDD in rails,it tests the business logic of application with controller and model tests. My Rails app has almost full coverage (around 85%-90%) with model and controller tests but still someone said that regression testing is not being performed on my application.

I have following concerns regarding rspecs :

1. Can we call combinations of model specs and controllers specs as integration testing? (i think yes but still want to confirm)
2. Can we call combination of model specs and controller specs as regression testing?
3. Feature specs written with cypybara can only be considers as regression testing?

Answer (score 0):

Regression testing is for end to end testing which means we have to cover user journey from front end which includes UI testing along with client side implementations this can not be achived by model specs and controller specs only , for these test cases we will need to write **feature specs** ie. cucumber with capybara